# Is there an easy way to do a complete synchron between two remote repos?

Tags: git

I have two remote repos, call it A and B. Both of them are fetch-ed (`git fetch --all --tags -f`) so I can see both of them.

I want:

- All commits, branches and tags of A to be pushed to B.
- All the commits, branches and tags of B, which do not exist on A, be deleted on B.

Is there an easy way to do that, or I need to write a script? It does not really matter, what happens in my local repo. I have no special access to any of the remote repos, but I can push/fetch with the git client as I want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git push --mirror B
```

See the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---mirror).

Comment: Will it also delete the branches/tags on B which do not exist on A?

Comment: From the linked doc: "*…deleted refs will be removed from the remote end…*" Read "deleted refs" simply as "absent in the local repo".